# Parse HH:mm:ss from CSV file

Tags: java, date, parsing

I'm loading a CSV file and need to parse two strings to localdate. Basically my project is about a Highscore list.

Example format in CSV file:  {David,18.01.2019,Easy,00:05:30}

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter timeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] highscore = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

    HighScore highScore = new HighScore(
        highscore[0],
        LocalDate.parse(highscore[1], dateFormat),
        highscore[2],
        LocalDate.parse(highscore[3], timeFormat));
    highScoreList.add(highScore);
```

It throws an exception when it tries to parse 00:05:30.

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '00:05:30' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 00:05:30 of type java.time.format.Parsed

Now I know this has something to do with the format I previously defined in timeFormat but I still don't see my mistake. I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Don't you want to use `LocalTime` when parsing the time column?

Comment: Didn't know that LocalTime exists. It works now thank you! Feel kind of dumb right now but I guess that's just normal for an inexperienced Java developer

Comment: 00:05:30, is that a duration, an amount of time? IN that case you need the `Duration` class (neither `LocalDate` nor `LocalTime`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you try to parse local time into a date.
In your case,you can use LocalTime object instead.

```
LocalTime.parse(highscore[3]);
```